# Swift map and filter: Find all factories that are not owned by a given player

Tags: arrays, swift, filtering, reducers

I have a Swift playground file where I have a list of factories with child entities called engines; where a player can hold many engines

The relationship is thus;

`Factory -> Engine <- Player`

- One factory has many engines
- One player has many engines
- One engine has a single parent (factory)
- One engine has a single owner (player)

I'm trying to build a Swift map and filter where, it produces a list of all factories that are **not** owned by a given player object.

My code now follows;

```
//: Swift Playground code
import Foundation

class Factory : CustomStringConvertible {
    var name: String = ""
    var engines: [Engine] = [Engine]()
    var description: String {
        return self.name
    }

    var owners: [Player]? {
        let filtered = self.engines.filter { (eng:Engine) -> Bool in
            return (eng.owner != nil)
            }
            .sorted { (engA:Engine, engB:Engine) -> Bool in
                return ((engA.owner?.turnOrder)! < (engB.owner?.turnOrder)!)
            }.flatMap { (eng:Engine) -> Player? in
                return (eng.owner)
        }

        return filtered
    }

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name

        // create 3 children (engines)
        for _ in 1...3 {
            let engine = Engine.init(parent: self)
            self.engines.append(engine)
        }
    }
}

class Engine : CustomStringConvertible {
    weak var parent: Factory?
    weak var owner: Player?

    var description: String {
        guard let hasParent = self.parent else {
            return "N/A"
        }
        return ("\(hasParent.name) - engine")
    }

    init(parent: Factory) {
        self.parent = parent
    }

    func setOwner(owner: Player) {
        self.owner = owner
        self.owner?.addEngine(engine: self)
    }
}

class Player : CustomStringConvertible {
    var name: String = ""
    var engines: [Engine] = [Engine]()
    var turnOrder: Int = 0
    var description: String {
        return self.name
    }

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    func addEngine(engine: Engine) {
        self.engines.append(engine)
    }
}

// create 3 factories
let f1 = Factory.init(name: "f1")
let f2 = Factory.init(name: "f2")
let f3 = Factory.init(name: "f3")
let factories = [f1,f2,f3]

let p1 = Player.init(name: "Bob")

if let firstEngine = f1.engines.first {
    firstEngine.setOwner(owner: p1)
}

print ("All factories: \(factories)")

print ("p1 = \(p1.name), engines: \(p1.engines)")

for (index, f) in factories.enumerated() {
    print ("#\(index), Owners: \(f.owners)")
}

// filter all factories NOT owned by player

let filtered = factories.map({ $0.engines.filter({ (eng: Engine) -> Bool in
        return (eng.owner != nil)
    })})

print ("factories not owned by player")

print (filtered)
```

The output is as follows:

```
All factories: [f1, f2, f3]
p1 = Bob, engines: [f1 - engine]
#0, Owners: Optional([Bob])
#1, Owners: Optional([])
#2, Owners: Optional([])
factories not owned by player
[[f1 - engine], [], []]
```

The issue I'm having is the last filter code;

```
// filter all factories NOT owned by player

let filtered = factories.map({ $0.engines.filter({ (eng: Engine) -> Bool in
        return (eng.owner != nil)
    })})
```

This only returns factories where engines are not nil,

I wish to use:

`return (eng.owner != p1)`

But an error is returned;

```
error: cannot convert value of type 'Player' to expected argument type '_OptionalNilComparisonType'
        return (eng.owner != p1)
```

I'm thus wondering, how can I filter a map of factories and only return a list of all factories where a given player does *not* own?

Many thanks

Comment: So a `Factory` `F` is "owned" by all `Player`s `P` who own `F`'s engines?

Comment: Perhaps I've mistaken my code or explanation.  Factory 1 (`f1`) has many engines.  `f1` is considered "owned" by Player 1 (`p1`) because p1 owns one of f1's engines.

Comment: If I understand correctly, that matches what I said

Comment: `var name: String = ""` Why do you assign a blank name to players by default? o.0

Comment: Just a point on design: I wouldn't make it the child's job to make itself a child of a parent its given. The other way around is usually simpler

Comment: I define it blank because I just testing it really quickly in Swift playground, the name I'm testing has no relevancy to the test except when I print to the logger

Comment: @Alex I like your idea, I had not considered this before.  I guess I'm still a lot to learn

Comment: Be careful, as you can see your "playground only" "just testing" code made it outside a playground.

Comment: okay, cool. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
extension Factory {
    func isOwned(by player: Player?) -> Bool {
        return self.engines.contains(where: { $0.isOwned(by: player)} )
    }
}

extension Engine {
    func isOwned(by player: Player?) -> Bool {
        return self.owner === player
    }
}

let factoriesNotOwnedByP1 = factories.filter { !$0.isOwned(by: p1) }
```

And here are some other changes I would make to your existing code:

```
import Foundation

class Factory {
    let name: String
    var engines = [Engine]()

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.engines += (1...3).map{ _ in Engine(parent: self) }
    }

    var owners: [Player]? {
        return self.engines
            .lazy
            .flatMap { engine in engine.owner.map{ (engine: engine, owner: $0) } }
            .sorted { $0.owner.turnOrder < $1.owner.turnOrder }
            .map { $0.owner }
    }

    func isOwned(by player: Player?) -> Bool {
        return self.engines.contains(where: { $0.isOwned(by: player)} )
    }
}

extension Factory: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String { return self.name }
}





class Engine {
    weak var parent: Factory?
    weak var owner: Player?

    init(parent: Factory) {
        self.parent = parent
    }

    func setOwner(owner: Player) {
        self.owner = owner
        self.owner?.addEngine(engine: self)
    }
}

extension Engine: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        guard let parent = self.parent else { return "N/A" }
        return ("\(parent.name) - engine")
    }
}





class Player {
    let name: String
    var engines = [Engine]()
    var turnOrder = 0

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    func addEngine(engine: Engine) {
        self.engines.append(engine)
    }
}

extension Player: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String { return self.name }
}

let factories = [
    Factory(name: "f1"),
    Factory(name: "f2"),
    Factory(name: "f3"),
]

let p1 = Player(name: "Bob")

factories.first?.engines.first?.setOwner(owner: p1)

print ("All factories: \(factories)")

print ("p1 = \(p1.name), engines: \(p1.engines)")

for (index, f) in factories.enumerated() {
    print("#\(index), Owners: \(String(describing: f.owners))")
}


let factoriesNotOwnedByP1 = factories.filter { !$0.isOwned(by: p1) }

print("factories not owned by player: ")
print(factoriesNotOwnedByP1)
```

Comment: I perhaps was really overcomplicating things, but many thanks for the assistance.

Comment: I got an error/bug on `return self.engines.contains(where: { $0.isOwned(by: player)} )`  I will try to resolve it

Comment: I was able to fix it by putting a function in the engines `func isOwned(by player: Player?) -> Bool { return self.engines.contains(where: { $0.isOwned(by: player)} )   }`   Sorry, I didn't see your earlier code; I apologize.

Comment: @zardon Yeah, you were overcomplicating. When you break down the problem into smaller steps, it becomes much simpler, and even english like. First you define ownership for Engine, then you define the ownership of a Factory being the set of all owners of its Engines. Simple!

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell swift what type .owner is:

```
let filtered = factories.map({ $0.engines.filter({ (eng: Engine) -> Bool in
    return (eng.owner as? Player != p1)
})})
```

Edit: It might actually be the 'p1' that needs to be set as Player, the error message doesn't specify.

Comment: Oh okay, I will look at this to see if this helps.   the error reporter now returns `downcast from 'Player?' to 'Player' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?
         return (eng.owner as? Player != p1)`

Comment: I tried to force unwrap the eng.owner as this can be nil but this also reported the same error